# Python: Appending large number of elements to list, does memory usage double during resizing?

Tags: python, memory-management

Let's assume I've an empty python list and I append elements to it

```
sample_list = []
for i in xrange(2**36):
   sample_list.append(str(i) + 'Test')
```

Python list is internally an array which it keeps re-sizing when it becomes full. When this resizing is happening for large array, how does the memory usage of process work, does it doubles?

Answer (score 0):

It will double several times, each time one of the appends pushes the used space past the threshold for resizing. More efficient would be to use one call to `extend`:

```
sample_list.extend([str(i) + 'Test' for i in xrange(2**36)])
```